# R unify data that have partial redundancy

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data like this

```
     B        A      Distance
 1: 1101053 1102060      3.8
 2: 1101053 1102065      6.1
 3: 1101053 1102067      5.8
 4: 1101053 1102068      4.0
 5: 1101053 1102069      5.1
 6: 1101053 1102069      6.0
 7: 1101053 1102069      7.0
 8: 1101053 1102069      6.6
 9: 1101053 1102069      6.6
10: 1101053 1103051      4.3
11: 1101053 1103052      5.6
```

In rows 5 to 9, they share the same values in columns B, A but different distances.
if I were to unify them with one distance (smallest), what would be the best solution?

The expected output would be

```
     B        A      Distance
 1: 1101053 1102060      3.8
 2: 1101053 1102065      6.1
 3: 1101053 1102067      5.8
 4: 1101053 1102068      4.0
 5: 1101053 1102069      5.1
 6: 1101053 1103051      4.3
 7: 1101053 1103052      5.6
```

I would appreciate some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(B, A) %>% filter(Distance == min(Distance))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   B, A [7]
        B       A Distance
    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1 1101053 1102060      3.8
2 1101053 1102065      6.1
3 1101053 1102067      5.8
4 1101053 1102068      4  
5 1101053 1102069      5.1
6 1101053 1103051      4.3
7 1101053 1103052      5.6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group-by and take the minimum value:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
     B        A      Distance
 1101053 1102060      3.8
 1101053 1102065      6.1
 1101053 1102067      5.8
 1101053 1102068      4.0
 1101053 1102069      5.1
 1101053 1102069      6.0
 1101053 1102069      7.0
 1101053 1102069      6.6
 1101053 1102069      6.6
 1101053 1103051      4.3
 1101053 1103052      5.6")
```

Solution using `data.table`:

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dat)
 dat[, .(Distance = min(Distance)), by=.(B, A)]

#>          B       A Distance
#> 1: 1101053 1102060      3.8
#> 2: 1101053 1102065      6.1
#> 3: 1101053 1102067      5.8
#> 4: 1101053 1102068      4.0
#> 5: 1101053 1102069      5.1
#> 6: 1101053 1103051      4.3
#> 7: 1101053 1103052      5.6
```

Solution using the `tidyverse`:

```
 library(dplyr)
 dat %>% 
   group_by(B, A) %>%
   summarize(Distance = min(Distance))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#> # Groups:   B [1]
#>         B       A Distance
#>     <int>   <int>    <dbl>
#> 1 1101053 1102060      3.8
#> 2 1101053 1102065      6.1
#> 3 1101053 1102067      5.8
#> 4 1101053 1102068      4  
#> 5 1101053 1102069      5.1
#> 6 1101053 1103051      4.3
#> 7 1101053 1103052      5.6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the brief explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `slice_min`

```
library(dplyr)   
df %>% 
    group_by(B, A) %>% 
    slice_min(Distance, n = 1)
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   B, A [7]
#        B       A Distance
#    <int>   <int>    <dbl>
#1 1101053 1102060      3.8
#2 1101053 1102065      6.1
#3 1101053 1102067      5.8
#4 1101053 1102068      4  
#5 1101053 1102069      5.1
#6 1101053 1103051      4.3
#7 1101053 1103052      5.6
```